# Windows 7 Issues

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I recently began to notice strange things happen to my Windows 7 x64 PC. It started off with a bluescreen every SECOND time I booted, then chrome refused to open zip files and virtualbox wouldn't let me select an iso (chrome and virtualbox are explorer issues by what I can tell) my search bar also doesnt work. I suspect this is an issue with windows and I am scanning my disk for errors. Anyone know anything else I can try before I reset my PC. EDIT: Bluescreens stopped after chkdsk /f now its just explorer and the search bar playing up

Answer (score -1):

You can search for more information on what might be happening in the Event Viewer. This contains a history of legged events from the Operating System and applications. It might indicate where the problem is coming from.
Search for "event viewer" in the Start Menu to open it.

Comment: -1 That should've been a comment.  You're just specifying something that might hint to whatever the problem is.  It's a good place to look but it's not the ultimate esolution.. just a place to look that may or may not  help find the solution. A simple comment of "check event viewer", or "why haven't you written what event viewer says e.g. check for red Xs" so as to prompt the questioner to add that info into his question.